# UIWebView load local html with cocos2d-js animaiton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, cocos2d-js

i hava some question about UIWebView load local html with cocos2d-js animaiton.
here is the thing:
the struct of the folder like :

Resources

```
 | -> www

          |->1
               | -> 1.html,1.js
               | -> res
                        | -> Cowboy.ExportJson,Cowboy.plist,Cowboy.png
```

. when i drag the folder in the xcode project ,i choose the "Create folder references" ,

i want load the "1.html", it will call the 1.js then show the animation, but the Cowboy Resources cannot load successful, i 
here's the codes:

i catch the exception something like did not get the resource...

i try 3 ways to load to my webView:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"www/1/1" withExtension:@"html"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]);
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]];


NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www/1"]];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl]];


 NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"www/1/1" withExtension:@"html"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *baseURL = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"www/1"];   self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:baseURL]];
```

buy they didn't work. who can help me . thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, check target build phase -> copy bundle resouces

Second, I think it should be NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"html"];

Third, use stringWithContentsOfFile not stringWithContentsOfURL

It should be like this -

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Hope it helps!